# Display graph in CSV file Angular 6

Tags: angular, export-to-csv, ng2-charts

I'm using ng-2 chart to represent some data in a chart format.
Everything is working fine and I'm able to show the graph on the webapp.
Now I need to print the data in the form of CSV.

Is there any way using which I can display the data (as in a webapp) in a chart format in CSV file.

Comment: Have you tried the AmChart package for the chart? 
It allows saving chart view or its data into various formats, like JPEG, PNG, PDF, XLSX, CSV, or JSON. You can check the demo here: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/exporting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to export the data in CVS format from the ng2-chart library. I checked the entire api and documentation [check here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) and nothing related was implemented.

Since you have your data in some form though, I would suggest that you use something like the following libraries

[Export to CSV](https://www.npmjs.com/package/export-to-csv)

[ngx-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-csv)

Both provide options on the generation but the first one is more popular so expect to find more documentation on it. The second one is simpler though.